# Styling text for textarea Wicket

Tags: java, css, textarea, wicket

I have got a string which consists of textlines. I would like to input these lines into a textarea with some css styles(eg changing the colour of some lines). How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

use tinymce editor. http://www.tinymce.com/
or you can use any kind of a Javascript WYSIWYG Editor

Add tinymce to page,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    // Skin options
    skin : "o2k7",
    skin_variant : "silver",

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "css/example.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'd still push for the Wicketstuff TinyMCE package.  Not necessarily easier, but more appropriate for a Wicket app.

Answer (score 1):

`TinyMCE` does do a pretty decent job of rendering CSS and other markup in an editor.

To include this easily with Wicket, I suggest the `org.wicketstuff.tinymce-parent` package.  The development/source code is in GitHub and the actual releases are in the public maven repository.

You can then use a standard Wicket TextArea component and add the TinyMCE behavior to it, instead of messing around with the javascript directly.

The one drawback is that, while TinyMCE is very mature, it also has some obscure bugs.  It's best to keep it simple, if at all possible.